# How do I pythonically set a value in a dictionary if it is None?

Tags: python, dictionary

This code is not bad, but I want to know how good programmers will write the code

```
if count.get('a') is None:
    count['a'] = 0
```

Comment: What if you intentionally put `None` as the value for `'a'`?

Comment: I don't think it's Pythonic to set values for keys in dictionaries to be `None`. Because if you do, then that can overlap with the return value of `get()` being `None` which may cause unnecessary bugs and confusion. Better to set the value to `0` or some zero-like non-None dummy class of sorts.

Comment: Just to make this clear: Do you want to account for the case when count['a'] is in fact `None`, or when count['a'] isn't defined? Or both?

Comment: @ShashankGupta You can specify the default value of `get` so that a value of `None` is not ambiguous. This may be useful when a 3rd party library expects `None` as a valid value with a certain meaning.

Comment: @Bakuriu thank you for the tip. I didn't know that the default could be overwritten. :)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can use `dict.setdefault` :

```
count.setdefault('a', 0)
```

help on `dict.setdefault`:

```
>>> print dict.setdefault.__doc__
D.setdefault(k[,d]) -> D.get(k,d), also set D[k]=d if k not in D
```

Answer (score 7):

`setdefault` is the best answer, but for the record, the Pythonic way to check for a key in a `dict` is using the `in` keyword:

```
if 'a' not in count:
    count['a'] = 0
```

Answer (score 4):

Looking at the selection of answer, I believe the question is somewhat incorrectly phrased.

> set a value in a dictionary if it is None?

In fact if the title is correct in asking about setting a value if it is `None`, `setdefault` doesn't set the value, instead returns that `None`.

```
a_dict = {'key': None}
assert a_dict.setdefault('key', True) is None
```

I don't think it's a very common situation when you want to update the dictionary if a key has a value of None (as opposed to not having that key at all, in which case the `setdefault` is the way to go.) or if it's not in there at all. In that case the following should work and seems the most pythonic to me.

```
if not a_dict.get('key'):
   a_dict['key'] = 'value'
```